# How can I infer no target in a target classification problem based on deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, mnist

Let's take the MNIST dataset (My application is different) with a lot of noise, I am going to train a deep NN to classify the letters.

What's the right way to infer, there's no letter possibility? or a letter not included in the training set?

Do I have to add the class "not a letter"  and try to pick or simulate the part of the dataset that has no letters but noise,

Or, I can do it without adding the extra label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is *anomaly detection*, or *novelty detection*.

This cannot always be solved by labeling some images as "no letter", since all kind of images having no letters may not be available for labeling, or maybe too costly to exhaustively label.

This [link](http://www.inf-cv.uni-jena.de/novelty_detection.html) has some directions you can look at for a start.

Answer (score 0):

For other people coming from search engines;

You can make your decision based on the output scores, if the network is confident enough about the assigned label you are going to see something like > 0.8 (for example) and extremely small scores for other classes.

However, if the network is not confident enough, score values will tend to take comparable values (especially while using a softmax at the end).

So combining this and the answer I marked as solving my question, I made an approach similar to novelty detection using KMeans to guess a threshold value below which the  input data is going to be considered as it doesn't go under any class label.